# Overflowing Content Background is white

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and have a container with rows, all overflowing content will get white background. Any idea where to look for?

This is just some example how the page looks like, not the original code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

    <title></title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      .....
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like the body keeps the size of the initial viewport size

Comment: you always should put your Original code

Comment: Posting a smaller example instead of all your original code is fine! As long, that is, as the example does demonstrate the problem. Your doesn't. I guess though that you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1coxwwmp/)?

Comment: You are right, but I cannot post the whole thing ;-) It is too much. I thought maybe this is a common issue which could be answered easily.

Comment: I don't have any idea where to look for, that is my problem.

Comment: Accidently I found the issue. Only body got background color and html was set to white.